# mermaid-cli Input file "/data/diagram.mmd" doesn't exist

Tags: docker, macos, mermaid

Following https://github.com/mermaid-js/mermaid-cli

On macOS, I installed it with docker

```
docker pull minlag/mermaid-cli
```

and then created `diagrams/diagram.mmd`

and then

```
docker run -it -v diagrams:/data minlag/mermaid-cli -i /data/diagram.mmd
```

and then

```
Input file "/data/diagram.mmd" doesn't exist
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that formattet like this:

```
docker run -it -v diagrams:/data minlag/mermaid-cli -i /data/diagram.mmd
```

It uses `diagrams` as a named-volume, not a path. Like this it should work, though is not so usefull:

```
docker run -it -v /full/path/to/diagrams:/data minlag/mermaid-cli -i /data/diagram.mmd
```

It's more cross-system-friendly if you replace the path with pwd, though then you also limit execution to the directory where the diagrams directory is located.

```
docker run -it -v `pwd`/diagrams:/data minlag/mermaid-cli -i /data/diagram.mmd
```